# Convert column's type in result of a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with two column (int , int),how can i write a query that result of this table is (int , varchar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select Column1, cast(Column2 as varchar(11)) as Column2
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the result set of your query in two ways

```
select Column1, CAST(Column2 as varchar(50)) as Column2
from Table1
```

or

```
select Column1, convert(varchar(50), Column2) as Column2
from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need your code to comply with ANSI standards, use CAST. If it doesn't matter, use CONVERT.

You can check the result of the conversion by using sql_variant_property:

```
SELECT Col1, 
       CAST(Col2 AS VARCHAR), 
       sql_variant_property(CAST(Col2 AS VARCHAR),'BaseType')
 FROM yourTable


SELECT Col1, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col2), 
       sql_variant_property(CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col2),'BaseType')
FROM yourTable
```